# How to specify alternate loader for intern

Tags: intern

Is there a way to specify an alternate AMD loader for intern?

I use [ESRI's ArcGIS API for JavaScript](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/) and unfortunately don't have access to their source code. So I'm stuck having to load their code from [here](http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/).

Their API is build on top of Dojo, so I'm thinking that I should be able to test with intern if I can point it at their loader instead of the one that comes with intern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Intern 1.2, you can specify an alternate AMD loader for the browser client by changing `<script src="node_modules/dojo/dojo.js"></script>` within `client.html`, and for the command-line client by changing `var req = require('dojo/dojo')` in `client.js`. It is not currently possible to change the test runner’s loader (`runner.js`) because the Node.js module loader relies on being able to find the overridden Node.js `require` in another specific (non-standard) location.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 

Is there an issue that I can follow for progress on allowing an alternative loader in client.js?

Comment: It should be possible today with Intern 1.2. Only the test runner (runner.js) will have difficulty.